# create multiple data table with column C# windows form

Tags: c#, datatable

i want to create multiple datatable and set some columns.

```
public partial class frmMain : frmTemplate
{
    DataTable dtguarantee = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtservice = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtsell = new DataTable();    

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dtguarantee.Columns.Add("Id");
        dtguarantee.Columns.Add("Serial");
        dtguarantee.Columns.Add("Guarantee");

        dtservice.Columns.Add("Id");
        dtservice.Columns.Add("Code");
        dtservice.Columns.Add("Fullname");
        dtservice.Columns.Add("Mobile");
        dtservice.Columns.Add("Address");
        dtservice.Columns.Add("ReciveDate");

        dtsell.Columns.Add("Id");
        dtsell.Columns.Add("SellName");
        dtsell.Columns.Add("SellProvince");
        dtsell.Columns.Add("SellCity");
        dtsell.Columns.Add("IsOurTeam");
        dtsell.Columns.Add("RequestType");
        dtsell.Columns.Add("Fullname");
        dtsell.Columns.Add("Mobile");
    }
}
```

but when i run my code see this error.

> **System.Data.DuplicateNameException: 'A column named 'Id' already belongs to this DataTable.'**

please help me immediately.

Comment: Try checking if it really contains column `Id`, on some reasons. Tell what does this return: `dtguarantee.Columns.Contains("Id")`

Comment: let me edit my question.

Comment: dtguarantee.Columns.Contains("Id") return true

Comment: since you're inheriting form `frmTemplate` check that you didn't already add columns in some base form's method, constructor etc

Comment: no DataTable in frmTemplate

Comment: So your `DataTable` really contains `Id` column. And your class `frmMain` is partial. Have you got access to its other part?

Comment: Maybe using **datatable.Columns.Clear();** just before adding new columns would work. Apparently, the DataTables are already created somewhere else in your code or are persisted as you are in a windows form environment. In addition, you should initialise the DataTables in the constructor just before adding the columns.

Comment: @SNBS what is your meaning of the other parts?

Comment: @Mahyar Mottaghi Zadeh test your suggest. not working.

Comment: @meysamrahpeyma [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) is explanation what are partial classes. Have you got access to other parts of your class?

Comment: @SNBS Yes i have

Comment: Then check whether the `Id` column was added there.